# Взвешенный граф

Tags: c++, графы

Есть точки вершин : 1(1,5), 2(3,2) и т.д. Вероятно для определения веса ребра.
Используется формула для вычисления длины отрезка на плоскости.
Далее есть список смежности: 1 2, 4 2, 3 1 и т.д.
Как это объединить? Т.е. вот составлю матрицу смежности, а вес к этому каким образом прибавить?

Comment: А элементами матрицы будут веса ребер...

Comment: Можете привести пример на коде ? И правильно ли я понял: т.е. допустим есть структура координат х,у и структура

Comment: и список смежности с полем для веса. Потом нужно по формуле вычислить вес и занести значение, а дальше построить матрицу смежности?

Comment: Сформулируйте точно, что вам надо, потому что пока я не могу понять точное задание...

Comment: "Некоторые элементы связаны между собой. Требуется от элемента, имеющего наибольшую суммарную длину связей с другими элементами , построить путь , не содержащий циклов" - само задание. У меня не получается построить матрицу, ибо нужно использовать точки вершин 1(1,5), 2(5,6) и т.д. со списком смежности.

Comment: Берете матрицу. Прописываете все ее элементы отрицательными значениями - это будет указание на то, что такого ребра нет. Далее берете список смежности, и для каждого элемента - скажем, 1 2, в элементы матрицы (граф неориентированный?) m[1][2] и m[2][1] вписываете вычисленное расстояние между точками 1 и 2. Вот и все. m[i][i] можно сделать нулевыми.

Comment: typedef struct{ int n1;int n2;} Nodes;
typedef struct{ double x; double y;} CoordXY;
int main(){double temp[4][4] = { { 0 } };static Nodes pNode[] = { { 1, 2 }, { 0, 1 }, { 1, 3 }, { 3, 2 } };static CoordXY pCord[] = { { 2, 6 }, { 10, 8 }, { 6, 10 }, { 8, 4 } };for (int r = 0; r < 4; r++){for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++){temp[pNode[r].n1][pNode[r].n2] = sqrt((pCord[r].x - pCord[j].x)*(pCord[r].x - pCord[j].x) + (pCord[r].y - pCord[j].y)*(pCord[r].y - pCord[j].y)); }} for (int t1 = 0; t1 < 4; t1++){for (int t2 = 0; t2 < 4; t2++)printf("%d ", temp[t1][t2]);printf("\n");}system("pause");return 0;}

Comment: В чем ошибка, помимо того, что не форматированный код в комментарии ?

Comment: Ну, как минимум `%d` вместо `%lf` в `printf`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот ваш правленный код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct
{
    int n1;
    int n2;
} Nodes;

typedef struct
{
    double x;
    double y;
} CoordXY;

int main()
{
    double temp[4][4] = { 0 };
    for (int r = 0; r < 4; r++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            temp[r][j] = (r==j) ? 0 : -1;

    static Nodes pNode[] = { { 1, 2 }, { 0, 1 }, { 1, 3 }, { 3, 2 } };
    static CoordXY pCord[] = { { 2, 6 }, { 10, 8 }, { 6, 10 }, { 8, 4 } };

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(pNode)/sizeof(pNode[0]); i++)
    {
        int from = pNode[i].n1;
        int to   = pNode[i].n2;
        double dx = pCord[from].x - pCord[to].x;
        double dy = pCord[from].y - pCord[to].y;
        temp[from][to] = temp[to][from] = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
    }

    for (int t1 = 0; t1 < 4; t1++)
    {
        for (int t2 = 0; t2 < 4; t2++)printf("%lf ", temp[t1][t2]);

        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

0 - для петли из себя в себя же :), -1 - отсутствие ребра.

Comment: О, спасибо большое =) А такой вопрос "..Требуется от элемента, имеющего наибольшую суммарную длину связей с другими элементами , построить путь , не содержащий циклов.." Это обход в глубину и поиск наидлиннейшего пути?

Comment: Путь куда, непонятно...

Comment: Чего не получается привинтить алгоритм Прима сюда =\